# Access yii extension controller from another controller

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I am working on building API in YII controller, we have a comment module which is an extension . I want to access comment extension's controller so that I can use the same functionality to be accessed for my API instead of creating one.

Can anyone tell me how can i do it?

Actually I am working on making API for my website. Where I have created a controller for API and accessing other controllers for functionality already exists. There's a functionality that exist in comment-module in extensions. And i need to access that Controller in comment-module. Hope this cleared my question asked above. And I need to access this function via Ajax as well, if possible. But should be accessed via API controller.

Specifying in case any confusion. My requirements would be:

- accessing methods of comment-module controller in only 1 method in API Controller. In order to make my functionality centeralized.
- comment-module should itself keep working.
- and work with API controller as well.

Note: Please explain your solutions as well, I am not a genius in yii like you.

Answer (score 0):

Move common functions into treat or inherit controller from extension.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Actually @benka, I am not sure what the poster meant by 'into treat'. However, the moving of the common functions into a common area, like components, will in fact address the OP's issue. But I also think Konstantin meant to say 'Inherit extension from controller', but said it the other way around.

Comment: @crafter thanks for your comment it makes sense :) A bit of rephrasing this answer would improve it's quality.

Comment: Don't fight guys. Anyone else know the answer??? And @konstantin How do I inherit controller from extensions. Such that it continue to work as well as solve my purpose as well.